# Unable to create a graph with syncfusion_flutter_charts in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, graph, charts

I am able to draw a graph in Android emulator but that graph is not working in Android physical device. It is showing gray screen instead of graph.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUpC5.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BspZR.jpg)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextTheme _textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    // TODO: implement build
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Image.network(
                    widget.cryptoData.cryptoImage!,
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    // fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 6,
                  ),
                  Text(widget.cryptoData.cryptoName!,
                      style: _textTheme.labelSmall),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  Text('(' + widget.cryptoData.cryptoSymbol! + ')',
                      style: _textTheme.titleMedium)
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 10),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                      "\$" +
                          limitDecimalToTwo(
                              widget.cryptoData.cryptoValue.toString()),
                      style: _textTheme.labelLarge),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(
                      limitDecimalToTwo(
                          widget.cryptoData.cryptoValueChange.toString()),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: widget.cryptoData.cryptoValueChange
                                      .toString()[0] ==
                                  '-'
                              ? Colors.red
                              : Colors.green,
                          fontSize: 14)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Container(
                  child: SfCartesianChart(
                    primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                    // primaryYAxis: CategoryAxis(
                    //     isVisible: false,
                    //     majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0)),
                    series: <ChartSeries<CryptoData, String>>[
                      LineSeries<CryptoData, String>(
                          dataSource: cryptoDataList,
                          xValueMapper: (CryptoData crypto, _) =>
                              getDateInProperFormat(crypto.date),
                          yValueMapper: (CryptoData crypto, _) => crypto.value),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: CryptoRowWidget(
                      cryptoName: widget.cryptoData.cryptoName,
                      cryptoCode: widget.cryptoData.cryptoSymbol,
                      cryptoImage: widget.cryptoData.cryptoImage,
                      cryptoValue: widget.cryptoData.cryptoValue.toString(),
                      cryptoValueChange:
                          widget.cryptoData.cryptoValueChange.toString(),
                      cryptoQunatityAvailable: '')),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: StadiumBorder()),
                        onPressed: () {
                          showAlertDialog(context, _textTheme, 'Buy');
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 10, 30, 10),
                            child: Text(
                              'Buy',
                              style: _textTheme.bodySmall,
                            ))),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 40,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: StadiumBorder()),
                        onPressed: () {
                          showAlertDialog(context, _textTheme, 'Sell');
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 10, 30, 10),
                            child: Text(
                              'Sell',
                              style: _textTheme.bodySmall,
                            ))),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72261344/6714054 You can find the answer for similar post but I don't have ListView as parent here.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: It is an open source it seems. As registration doesn't required to use for syncfusion_flutter_charts in your project as per this information provided here.. https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/licensing/overview

Comment: You don't need to *register* them, but the syncfusion products require that you comply with their license regardless of any registration system.  And that's the concern I raised in my previous comment. It is definitely *not* open source.